# Handling null value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function written as follows:

```
function refresh(selection, xPath, yPath, xAnnotationSelection, yAnnotationSelection) {
      var coords = selection.node().__coord__;
      ...
}
```

The function is being called sometimes, with the variable `selection` not having been set yet, which causes the following exception to be thrown:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '**coord**' of null

What is a better way to write the statement so that it first checks to make sure that `selection` is not null, before attempting to call a method on it?

Pseudocode:

```
var coords = (selection ? ((selection.node ? selection.node().__coord__: null) : null);
```

Comment: Your pseudocode should work if you change selection.node to selection.node()

Comment: did you meaning you want at first check if the selection then do in it not found it should be default value null

Comment: coords = selection ? (selection.node() ? selection.node().__coord__: null) : null;

Comment: Use a ternary operator only for simple to read expressions. For anything else go with regular `if` statements. The goal of good code is not to create fancy one-liners, but to create easily understandable and maintainable code.

Comment: or can be best 
   

     coords = selection ? (selection.node() ? selection.node().__coord__: null) : null;

or simple this code

    const section2= selection.node()?selection.node().__coord__: null;
    const coords=selection?section2:null


or can used as if statment 

   

     const icoords=null;
    if(selection&&selection.node()){
    
      icoords=selection.node().__coord__
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can write -:

```
var coords = selection && selection.node && selection.node().__coord__;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way for your function is:

```
function refresh(selection, xPath, yPath, xAnnotationSelection, yAnnotationSelection) {
  const node = selection && selection.node();
  if (!node) {
    return null;
  }
  var coords = node.__coord__;
  ...
}
```